# Accessing json payload values in stored in Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a map

```
Map<String, Object> PayloadDb;
```

which contains json payload
like

> {
> name: messenger ,version: 1.0.0,payload:{name=test,color=red, other
> values}
> }
> I am getting all these filed from DB table
> DB table has a column which stores CLOB - json
> After storing the record in Map it looks like:

```
My HashMap contains
[0] service
[1] version
[2] payload - 
    [0] key name
    value test
    [1] key color
            red
```

and so on

```
  payload key of the hashmap contains key value pairs
```

i am able to get name and version from the Map

How can i access the payload element values stored in Map?

Comment: Cast the result of `map.get(“payload”)` to a `Map<String,Object>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the payload attribute of json in the following way:

```
Map<String,Object> payload = (Map<String,Object>) PayloadDb.get("payload");
```

Once you have the payload map above, you can get its attributes by `payload.get("name");`

Make sure you do a null check before getting payload attributes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Nitin ,But that is not the case,I have updated the question

Comment: Then I suppose Edwin's solution should work for you. Try doing `Map<String,Object> payload = (Map<String,Object>) PayloadDb.get("payload");` And then you can get the values by `payload.get("name")`.

Comment: Let me know if it works for you so that I can edit the original answer for anyone viewing it.